# Regex to extract non standard date format

Tags: regex

I need a regex to grab the date section (i.e 23 March 2014) from a string with the following format:

> 23 March 2014 and includes 50,000 67 A Part 500

I have tried the below but it doesnt work, any ideas?

```
preg_match("/[0-9]+[ ][a-zA-Z][ ][201][0-9]$/",$str,$matchx);
```

I am using PHP

Answer (score 0):

you need to have the right quantifiers; don't use a class for the string `201` or spaces (although the former is more troublesome than the latter), and you have to allow for things that come after the date (so get rid of the `$`):

```
preg_match("/[1-9][0-9]? [A-Z][a-zA-Z]+ 201[0-9]/",$str,$matchx);
```

By the way - the form I chose does not allow for `09 March` - it won't let you have a leading zero, and it expects the first letter of the month to be capitalized. You can easily change that back of course.

Test:

```
<?php
$str="23 March 2014 and includes 50,000 67 A Part 500";
preg_match("/[1-9][0-9]? [A-Z][a-zA-Z]+ 201[0-9]/",$str,$matchx);
print_r($matchx);
?>
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 23 March 2014
)
```